# How to do digest authentication in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I have an apache2 server running on Ubuntu. I'm new to Apache, so forgive me I say something illogical.

I have basic authentication working, so I thought I'd just replicate the directives for digest authentication, but I'm guessing that's where I'm going wrong.

```
<Directory /home/mark/.www/secret>
    <Files file1>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Secret"
      AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/conf-available/.htpasswd"
      Require valid-user
    </Files>

    <Files file2>
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Secret"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/conf-available/.htpasswd"
        Require valid-user bob
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

In /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, auth_basic.load was already there as a symbolic link to /etc/apache2/mods-available

Therefore, I created a symbolic link for auth_digest.

However, I still get a 401 error when loading file2 (yes, I am restarting the server when making changes).

Both file1 and file2 have permissions 644 and like I said file1 successfully loads with basic auth.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same password file for both auth methods, but they need password files in different formats.

Password files for the digest method can be created with `htdigest` and contain the realm name.

```
cat .htpasswd.digest
sven:test:89bf07ca6d68de56df750411b4d41658

cat .htpasswd
sven:$apr1$is4DJFgn$SNilHKs4CqblmS0GsBiFu0
```

A remark: I would suggest to use Basic Auth instead of Digest, but **only** via a secure TLS connection.